# How to use mesh.bounds in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently created simple level generator, which creates a level with segments. I used `mesh.bounds.x` to see how far from the previous segment that the next segment should be placed. It worked for me pretty well, because all segments were square. Now I decided to make this work with bigger segments with the other sides proportions(still quite rectangular). My problem is that even though I tried many combinations I couldn't set this up properly.

Can somebody explain to me how this `mesh.bound` works? I also instantiate rotated segments, maybe this causes some bugs? All my prefabs are imported from blender.

There is part of my code where I instantiate one segment(before I decided to use more complex segments):

```
size = meshh.bounds.size;

if ((x == 0) && (y == 0))
{
     segments[x, y] = Instantiate(prefabs[0], new Vector3(segments[1, 1].transform.position.x - size.x, segments[1, 1].transform.position.y, segments[1, 1].transform.position.z + size.x), segments[1, 1].transform.rotation) as GameObject;

     segments[x, y].tag = "Terrain";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your specific problem is that a bounding box makes a **square** box in **world space** ... that is to say "axis-aligned".

AABB stands for ***AXIS ALIGNED*** bounding box.

It ***IS NOT*** the "bounds" as you would think of "bounds" in the conventional English meaning of that word.

Exactly as you say, if you have a rotated object, it gives you the biggest "flat" box in world space which holds the thing.

This is a basic in 3D engineering.

[image]

The diagrams show some "AABB" "axis-aligned" bounding boxes in 2D.  Same applies in 3D.

(Once you deal with this in an advanced way, be careful too because the *mesh's* bounds are confusingly AABB bounds **in Unity-local space** i.e. in the parent's space - use renderer.bounds for scene-space - don't worry about this until you get in to it  :) There are different "bounds" you can use in Unity, all of them confusing.)

By the way -- one KISS way to deal with this if you're just starting out: simply, rotate the object until it is square, ie no rotation. *Then* get the measurement!  Then rotate it to where you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Bounds describe the the smallest box your mesh would fit in. Box is in **world** space. Basically like these white corners in 3ds Max:

[image: 3dsMax selection box]

[Mesh.bounds on Unity Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html)

Comment: I corrected a typo - the idea of an AABB box is that indeed it is in world space.