# In Unity, get the mesh, or otherwise get local bounds on a Sprite?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, aabb

This question **only relates to the Unity game engine**.

Here's a visual example of a **so-called Unity "sprite"** (Unity Sprite class) which is a thin 3D object.

[image] [image]

AABB shown (green lines). In Unity, live AABB off the gpu is given via `.bounds` ([doco](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html)). If new to CG, [explanation of AABB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36202761/294884).

(Note, "local" in Unity ([doco](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html), [doco](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html)) means: in the quaternion of the parent object; "world" means in the quaternion of the scene object.)

Now! For any Unity engineers reading:

Normally in Unity, with a visible object, when you want to get the [Unity Bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html),

if you want them in world space, `renderer.bounds` returns the [Unity Bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) in world space.

if you want them in local space, `mesh.bounds` returns the [Unity Bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) in local space.

This is a basic of Unity and you do it all the time. However.  With the new sprite, that is to say `SpriteRenderer`, there's **no real access to the mesh** as far as I know.

(You can actually get the .triangles, but it would be quite a chore to reconstruct the winding and size from there.)

How then, can you get the **local** [Unity Bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) for a Sprite?

(Note that `sprite.bounds` itself is just the same `renderer.bounds`, that doesn't help.)

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. +1

Comment: some non-Unity folks did not understand that a "sprite" class in unity is a 3D object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for `SpriteRenderer.sprite.bounds`.

```
public class LogBounds : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnGUI () {
        var r = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        GUILayout.Label("SpriteRenderer.bounds center " + r.bounds.center + " size " + r.bounds.size);
        GUILayout.Label("SpriteRenderer.sprite.bounds center " + r.sprite.bounds.center + " size " + r.sprite.bounds.size);
    }
}
```

[image: example]

Note that the values for SpriteRenderer.sprite.bounds do not change as the transform's properties are changed -- those values are in local coordinates.

Comment: Sorry but that's definitely incorrect. SpriteRenderer.bounds and SpriteRenderer.sprite.bounds return different values.

Comment: `Sprite` exposes `vertices` `triangles` and `uv` properties, which is all you need to make a decent `Mesh`. I'm not sure what other mesh-like properties you'd be interested in that would still be applicable to a Sprite or not easily inferred (e.g. normals)